# Python convert dwg file to shapefile

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm new on python. I want to convert dwg file to shapefile. I found some code. When I run the code I get an error. How can I solve this problem? Here the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Merve\Desktop\dwgtoshp\dwg2shp.py", line 91, in 
>       arcpy.IterateDatasets_mb(dwg_dosyalari, "", "", "NOT_RECURSIVE")
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'IterateDatasets_mb'

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# dwg2shp.py
# Created on: 2017-01-30 13:59:57.00000
#   (generated by ArcGIS/ModelBuilder)
# Usage: dwg2shp <pro_id> <pro_tip> <dwg_dosyalari> <Name> <Cikti_yeri> <line_merge_shp> <anno_merge_shp> 
# Description: 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Load required toolboxes
arcpy.ImportToolbox("C:\Users\Merve\Desktop\dwg\dwg2shp.tbx")

# Script arguments
pro_id = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if pro_id == '#' or not pro_id:
    pro_id = "1000888" # provide a default value if unspecified

pro_tip = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
if pro_tip == '#' or not pro_tip:
    pro_tip = "33" # provide a default value if unspecified

dwg_dosyalari = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
if dwg_dosyalari == '#' or not dwg_dosyalari:
    dwg_dosyalari = "F:\\proje\\gelen" # provide a default value if unspecified

Name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
if Name == '#' or not Name:
    Name = "Dataset" # provide a default value if unspecified

Cikti_yeri = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
if Cikti_yeri == '#' or not Cikti_yeri:
    Cikti_yeri = "C:\Users\Merve\Desktop\dwgtoshp\yenidwgdosyaları" # provide a default value if unspecified

line_merge_shp = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
if line_merge_shp == '#' or not line_merge_shp:
    line_merge_shp = "C:\Users\Merve\Desktop\dwgtoshp\yenidwgdosyaları" # provide a default value if unspecified

anno_merge_shp = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)
if anno_merge_shp == '#' or not anno_merge_shp:
    anno_merge_shp = "C:\Users\Merve\Desktop\dwgtoshp\yenidwgdosyaları" # provide a default value if unspecified

# Local variables:
Dataset = "C:\Users\Merve\Desktop\dwgtoshp\dwgdosyaları"
Annotation = Dataset
Polyline = Dataset
v1_shp__5_ = Polyline
dosya_line = "1.shp"
kat_3_bodrum_3_line_shp = v1_shp__5_
New_Field___4_ = kat_3_bodrum_3_line_shp
pro_id_field = "pro_id"
long = "LONG"
New_Field___5_ = New_Field___4_
pro_tip_field = "pro_tip"
Field_Type__6_ = "LONG"
New_Field___6_ = New_Field___5_
plan_adi_field = "plan_adi"
text = "TEXT"
v1_shp__2_ = New_Field___6_
v1_shp__6_ = v1_shp__2_
v1_shp__4_ = v1_shp__6_
Output_Values = v1_shp__4_
kat_3_bodrum_3_line_Merge__2_ = line_merge_shp
bodrum_3_anno_shp__2_ = Annotation
sil__3_ = "C:\Users\Merve\Desktop\dwgtoshp\yenidwgdosyaları"
dosya_anno = "1.shp"
kat_0_zemin_anno_shp__2_ = bodrum_3_anno_shp__2_
New_Field_ = kat_0_zemin_anno_shp__2_
New_Field___3_ = New_Field_
New_Field___2_ = New_Field___3_
v1_shp = New_Field___2_
v1_shp__3_ = v1_shp
kat_0_zemin_anno_shp = v1_shp__3_
Output_Values__2_ = kat_0_zemin_anno_shp
merge_shp__2_ = anno_merge_shp

# Set Geoprocessing environments
arcpy.env.MTolerance = ""
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = "PROJCS['ITRF_1996_UTM_Zone_35N',GEOGCS['GCS_ITRF_1996',DATUM['D_ITRF_1996',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',30.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',1.0],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]"
arcpy.env.outputZFlag = "Disabled"
arcpy.env.outputZValue = ""
arcpy.env.outputMFlag = "Disabled"
arcpy.env.geographicTransformations = ""
arcpy.env.ZResolution = ""
arcpy.env.MResolution = ""
arcpy.env.ZTolerance = ""

# Process: Iterate Datasets
arcpy.IterateDatasets_mb(dwg_dosyalari, "", "", "NOT_RECURSIVE")

# Process: Select Data (2)
arcpy.SelectData_management(Dataset, "Polyline")

# Process: Calculate Value (3)
arcpy.CalculateValue_management("\"%Name%\"+\"_line\"", "", "String")

# Process: Feature Class to Feature Class (2)
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(Polyline, Cikti_yeri, dosya_line, "", "", "DocName")

# Process: Delete Field (2)
arcpy.DeleteField_management(v1_shp__5_, "Entity;Handle;LyrFrzn;LyrLock;LyrOn;LyrVPFrzn;LyrHandle;EntColor;LyrColor;BlkColor;Linetype;EntLinetyp;LyrLnType;BlkLinetyp;Elevation;Thickness;LineWt;EntLineWt;LyrLineWt;BlkLineWt;RefName;LTScale;ExtX;ExtY;ExtZ;DocName;DocPath;DocType;DocVer;Owner;ScaleX;ScaleY;ScaleZ;FontID;Height;TxtAngle;TxtWidth;TxtOblique;TxtGenType;TxtJust;VertAlign;TxtFont;TxtBoxHt;TxtBoxWd;TxtRefWd;TxtAttach;TxtDir;LnSpace;SpaceFct;TxtMemo;EntLinetype;BlkLinetype")

# Process: Add Field (4)
arcpy.AddField_management(kat_3_bodrum_3_line_shp, pro_id_field, long, "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Add Field (5)
arcpy.AddField_management(New_Field___4_, pro_tip_field, Field_Type__6_, "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Add Field (6)
arcpy.AddField_management(New_Field___5_, plan_adi_field, text, "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Calculate Field (4)
arcpy.CalculateField_management(New_Field___6_, "pro_id", pro_id, "VB", "")

# Process: Calculate Field (5)
arcpy.CalculateField_management(v1_shp__2_, "pro_tip", pro_tip, "VB", "")

# Process: Calculate Field (6)
arcpy.CalculateField_management(v1_shp__6_, "plan_adi", "\"%Name%\"", "VB", "")

# Process: Collect Values
arcpy.CollectValues_mb("F:\\gis_workspace\\sil\\1.shp")

# Process: Merge
tempEnvironment0 = arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = "C:\Users\Merve\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb"
arcpy.Merge_management(Output_Values, line_merge_shp, "pro_id \"pro_id\" true true false 0 Long 0 0 ,First,#,F:\\gis_workspace\\sil\\1.shp,pro_id,-1,-1;pro_tip \"pro_tip\" true true false 0 Long 0 0 ,First,#,F:\\gis_workspace\\sil\\1.shp,pro_tip,-1,-1;plan_adi \"plan_adi\" true true false 0 Text 0 0 ,First,#,F:\\gis_workspace\\sil\\1.shp,plan_adi,-1,-1")
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = tempEnvironment0

# Process: Repair Geometry
arcpy.RepairGeometry_management(line_merge_shp, "DELETE_NULL")

# Process: Select Data
arcpy.SelectData_management(Dataset, "Annotation")

# Process: Calculate Value (2)
arcpy.CalculateValue_management("\"%Name%\"+\"_anno\"", "", "String")

# Process: Feature Class to Feature Class
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(Annotation, sil__3_, dosya_anno, "", "", "DocName")

# Process: Delete Field
arcpy.DeleteField_management(bodrum_3_anno_shp__2_, "Entity;Handle;Owner;LyrFrzn;LyrLock;LyrOn;LyrVPFrzn;LyrHandle;EntColor;LyrColor;BlkColor;Linetype;EntLinetyp;LyrLnType;BlkLinetyp;Elevation;Thickness;LineWt;EntLineWt;LyrLineWt;BlkLineWt;RefName;LTScale;ExtX;ExtY;ExtZ;DocName;DocPath;DocType;DocVer;ScaleX;ScaleY;ScaleZ;FontID;Height;TxtAngle;TxtWidth;TxtOblique;TxtGenType;TxtJust;VertAlign;TxtFont;TxtBoxHt;TxtBoxWd;TxtRefWd;TxtAttach;TxtDir;LnSpace;SpaceFct;TxtMemo;EntLinetype;BlkLinetype")

# Process: Add Field
arcpy.AddField_management(kat_0_zemin_anno_shp__2_, pro_id_field, long, "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Add Field (3)
arcpy.AddField_management(New_Field_, pro_tip_field, Field_Type__6_, "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Add Field (2)
arcpy.AddField_management(New_Field___3_, plan_adi_field, text, "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Calculate Field
arcpy.CalculateField_management(New_Field___2_, "pro_id", pro_id, "VB", "")

# Process: Calculate Field (2)
arcpy.CalculateField_management(v1_shp, "pro_tip", pro_tip, "VB", "")

# Process: Calculate Field (3)
arcpy.CalculateField_management(v1_shp__3_, "plan_adi", "\"%Name%\"", "VB", "")

# Process: Collect Values (2)
arcpy.CollectValues_mb("C:\Users\Merve\Desktop\dwgtoshp\yenidwgdosyaları")

# Process: Merge (2)
arcpy.Merge_management(Output_Values__2_, anno_merge_shp, "pro_id \"pro_id\" true true false 0 Long 0 0 ,First,#,F:\\gis_workspace\\sil\\1.shp,pro_id,-1,-1;pro_tip \"pro_tip\" true true false 0 Long 0 0 ,First,#,F:\\gis_workspace\\sil\\1.shp,pro_tip,-1,-1;plan_adi \"plan_adi\" true true false 0 Text 0 0 ,First,#,F:\\gis_workspace\\sil\\1.shp,plan_adi,-1,-1")

# Process: Repair Geometry (2)
arcpy.RepairGeometry_management(anno_merge_shp, "DELETE_NULL")
```

Answer (score 0):

`IterateDatasets` is a tool [designed for use only in ModelBuilder](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-datasets.htm).

To accomplish the same in a Python script, you need to build a list of datasets ([`arcpy.ListDatasets`](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/listdatasets.htm)) and then iterate through it with a standard for loop, e.g.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = dwg_dosyalari   # sets workspace to use
datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets()
for dataset in datasets:
    # do things
```